# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] ToArray[String] except when using SqlQuery method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

i have a problem using a function that is very strange for me:

**Using C# MVC Framework 4**

I have this function declared in a repository class that i invoke inside a controller:

```
public IQueryable<Bus> Search(string[] states)
{
    // Give all the buses that are inside the list of states that i giving you, no matter upper case or lower case

    IQueryable<Bus> query = this.context.Buses;
    if (states.Length > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(b => states.Select(s => s.ToLower()).ToArray().Contains(b.State.ToLower()));
    }
    return query;
}
```

When i execute the action using this function i get the error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '**System.String[] ToArray[String]**
...
...
...
```

But there is an exception, if i change the code like this (using **SqlQuery** function before anything else):

```
public IQueryable<Bus> Search(string[] states)
{
    // Give all the buses that are inside the list of states that i giving you, no matter upper case or lower case

    IQueryable<Bus> query = this.context.Buses.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Buses").AsQueryable();
    if (states.Length > 0)
    {
        query = query.Where(b => states.Select(s => s.ToLower()).ToArray().Contains(b.State.ToLower()));
    }
    return query;
}
```

When I execute the same action there is no problem. Does someone know why is that?

I know that the function **SqlQuery** return an **DbSqlQuery** object but after that I transform that object to a **Queryable** and for some reason this object still allows me to use the **ToArray** function.

Is there a way to do the same thing without the use of **SqlQuery** function? I tried to import all these packages (that are included in the **DbSqlQuery** class declaration hoping that there is an extension declared but no):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
```

Any help? Recommendation? Something?

Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution that i found was simple, i just use the **ToArray** function **before** the where statement like this:

```
public IQueryable<Bus> Search(string[] states)
{
    // Give all the buses that are inside the list of states that i giving you, no matter upper case or lower case

    IQueryable<Bus> query = this.context.Buses;
    if (states.Length > 0)
    {
        states = states.Select(s => s.ToLower()).ToArray();
        query = query.Where(b => states.Contains(b.State.ToLower()));
    }
return query;
}
```

Thanks to *insta* for his help.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlQuery` is `IEnumerable`.  When you execute that, the database is done.  Afterwards, you call `.AsQueryable` (which will TRY to give you a Queryable, but will give you an IEnumerable that looks like an IQueryable if it can't).  The .ToArray is happening in memory on the client side rather than the server side.

Comment: Thanks, that was very clear i will search for a better way to manage this and upload the solution.